# HTTPS on Cocos2d-x

Tags: security, https, game-engine, cocos2d-x

I'm implementing a game app based on cocos2d-x. In order to technically prevent cheating, one of the ideas to do is using HTTPS for all the client-server communication, which make it difficult to get the data format / game logic and send modified request to cheat. (I know "prevent" is actually impossible but for increasing the cost of making game cheating it's ok : ). My question is,

1. In Cocos2d-x, how to make HTTPS request? Possible?
2. In a more general case, technically what to do to reduce such game hacking? What strategy to hold?

Answer (score 2):

For native cross platform C++ networking you may consider using Boost C++ libraries. Boost.Asio is the one used for networking.

Boost.Asio link:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Boost.Asio tutorials link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html

Although not officially supported (only due to lack of regression testing on iOS and Android),  Boost runs without any problems on iOS and Android (and probably other C++ based mobile platforms as well).

To prevent cheating you usually rely on an external source (which can be your game server) e.g. if your game relies on the time of day you may get the time form an external server. You may use encryption libraries for data transfer on the client and server side.

Comment: Thanks alot though it's not a fresh post. : )

Comment: Yes I realize that it's not a fresh post, still I felt the need to answer this question since people usually have issues with cross platform networking in C++.

Answer (score 0):

by using curl library you can make https connection.
if you want technically protect your game use you own strong encryption technique.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a problem we face all the time. If the cheating is limited to the cheater's instance the questions is academical and should be studied on your spare time.

On the other hand when your income is impacted or when the cheater's actions impact other players and degrade the game experience you should put some effort on testing the game state for inconsistencies, secure the client/server transactions and deal with cheating in very subtle ways to avoid completely deterring the cheaters' interest.

C++ https implementations are available with curl and boost.

Concerning the game data, the simplest way to test for inconsistencies are scores. You can add a few indicators to avoid polluting your leaderboards. You can add special checksums based on the score's components (time spent in game, number of power ups and score multipliers received...) if you can recalculate the score on the server and if inconsistencies are discovered you can deal with it.

Also you can grab instants of the game state and a few commands, encode that and replay the sequences on the server to check for inconsistencies. Deal with cheaters however you like.

When playing on a server let the server manage the gamestate and allow no client side game state changes that would impact players. Check for input consistency etc...

When using micro transactions each micro transaction should be verified with the vendors servers before being fully committed to the player's account.

Even if these papers [1](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking), [2](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization) from valve refer to fps games they should give you some pointers as to how to deal with state inconsistencies (introduced by communication delays). It should help in avoiding fake positives and ruining the experience for non cheaters.